# How to recover a folder deleted in Notes app?

Tags: icloud, notes.app

My saved Notes on my iPad  were accidentally deleted.  I tried to find a folder for the "recently deleted" and there is none listed, how do I find it?

Answer (score 1):

I like to go to a computer and sign in to iCloud directly.

Much easier to see what’s deleted and diagnose if an iPad or iPhone is behind in syncing up to the cloud. If one device lags, I like to power it off while it’s in an area where WiFi works and plug into charge.

That wakes the device and I unlock it only long enough to verify the WiFi reconnected. Let it sit an hour or overnight and most iCloud sync issues fix themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be on the left hand side under your normal notes.

[image]

Note that this only works with iCloud notes. If your notes were stored on your Gmail or other email account, they are gone.

If they were indeed stored on iCloud, I'd do as bmike recommends, and wait it out on desktop.